Why mirror not showing half of the model

Why mirror modifier not showing half of the model when display is off. Only the top handle is seen half. I have check duplicate faces also. Whats going wrong any suggestion or help.


That's because your object is not half to begin with, it's a full model with only the handle being half. You can see that when you remove all modifiers. Also please read this answer that should help understand the problem.

So when you turn the display on, it shows the handle, however it doesn't show the vertices, edges, or faces for that half of the handle. That is because the mirror modifier is not applied. But you do see the vertices, edges, and faces of the half of the base.
You are seeing the mirrored base even with the mirror turned off because you already applied a previous mirror modifier to the base, but not to the handle.
So when you turn the current mirror modifier on you are putting 2 halfs on top of eachother.
To fix this you can just manually delete the half of the base where it should be mirrored to.
